# Grouping array elements in the correct order on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

Is it possible to group array elements in PostgreSQL?

Example, I have 2 related arrays like this (I say related because the first array indicates actions and the second array represents those action's times:

```
col0 = 'any_value'
col1 = array1['a','b','b','c','c','a','a','a','c']
col2 = array2[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and I would like to output the following result:

```
col0 = 'any_value'
array_result1['a','b','c','a','c']    
array_result2[1,2,4,6,9]
```

A way the array can be unnested is by using ordinality, this is an example query, but it returns a distinct selection of the array elements which removes the repeated ones:

```
select col0, 
       array_agg(x order by rn) as unique_array1
        from (
              select 
              distinct on (col0, a.x) col0, 
                           a.x, 
                           a.rn
              from table_a, 
                   unnest(array1) with ordinality as a (x,rn)
              order by 1,2,3  
             ) unnested_ordered
group by col0;
```

So the result of this would be:

```
col0 = 'any_value'
array_result1['a','b','c']
```

But as you can see it is missing many elements.

**EDIT:**

To describe more my issue, In the end I would like to know when each of the array_result1 actions are initially done.
So for the example result

```
array_result1['a','b','c','a','c']    
*array_result2[1,2,4,6,9]
```

*I supose the position of the array starts at 1 and not 0, i also fixed the last element, it should be 9 not 7

would help me to know, when did the first action 'a' happen and when did the second action 'a' happen so I can calculate the time for action 'a' to return into the path I am building.
So first time action 'a' happened was = 1
Second time it happened was = 6

So action 'a' appears twice in the path(array) and it takes 5 time units to re appear. That is why I need the second array with the times on which the actions happened (the first time each action happened)

Comment: I do not understand your second result. Shouldn't it be `1,2,4,6,9`?

Comment: no, the position of the letter is what matters, its like grouping by subgroups of letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `LATERAL` and calculate group using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a;
CREATE TABLE table_a(col0 VARCHAR(10), col1 text[],col2 int[]);

INSERT INTO table_a(col0, col1, col2)
VALUES ('any_value',array['a','b','b','c','c','a','a','a','c'],
        array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
```

Main query:

```
SELECT col0,
       col1,
       unique_col1
FROM table_a,
LATERAL (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY grp) AS unique_col1
         FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT x,
                 rn - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x ORDER BY rn) AS grp
               FROM unnest(col1) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(x,rn)
         ) AS sub      
) AS lat1
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Calculating second array:

```
SELECT col0,
       col1,
       unique_col1,
       col2,
       unique_col2
FROM table_a,
LATERAL (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY grp) AS unique_col1
         FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT x,
                 rn - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x ORDER BY rn) AS grp
               FROM unnest(col1) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(x,rn)
         ) AS sub      
) AS lat1,
LATERAL (
   SELECT array_agg(x ORDER BY rn) AS unique_col2
   FROM unnest(col2) WITH ORDINALITY AS b(x,rn)
   WHERE rn IN (
         SELECT SUM(c) OVER(ORDER BY grp) - (c-1) AS result
         FROM (SELECT grp,  COUNT(*) AS c
               FROM ( SELECT x,
                             rn - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x ORDER BY rn)  AS grp
                      FROM unnest(col1) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(x,rn)
               ) AS sub     
          GROUP BY grp) AS s
    )      
) AS lat2
```

[image]

Remark:

It generates second array from values, not its position, so when you have:

```
col2 = array[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

you will get:

```
[9,8,6,4,1]
```

If you want only positions you could use:

```
...
LATERAL (
   SELECT array_agg(result ORDER BY result) AS unique_col2
   FROM (
         SELECT SUM(c) OVER(ORDER BY grp) - (c-1) AS result
         FROM (SELECT grp,  COUNT(*) AS c
               FROM ( SELECT x,
                             rn - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x ORDER BY rn) AS grp
                      FROM unnest(col1) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(x,rn)
               ) AS sub     
          GROUP BY grp) AS s
    ) AS s1    
) AS lat2
```

And the result will be:

```
[1,2,4,6,9]
```

## EDIT 2

In above version there is small mistake. The `ARRAY_AGG` should be ordered by `rn` not `grp`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a;
CREATE TABLE table_a(col0 VARCHAR(10), col1 text[],col2 int[]);

INSERT INTO table_a(col0, col1, col2)
VALUES ('any_value',array['a','b','b','c','c','a','a','a','c'],
        array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);

INSERT INTO table_a(col0, col1, col2)
VALUES ('any_value2',array['a','b','a','a','c','a'],array[1,2,3,4,5,6]);        


SELECT *
FROM table_a,
LATERAL (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY rn) AS unique_col1
         FROM
           (SELECT x, grp, MIN(rn) AS rn
            FROM (SELECT  x,
                       rn - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x ORDER BY rn) AS grp,
                       rn
                  FROM unnest(col1) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(x,rn)
           ) AS sub
         GROUP BY x, grp) AS s      
        ) AS lat1;
```

[image]

Comment: Wow nice, although just to understand, if I add an array of grp, I get something like this for the first row for example:
"{0,1,3,4,6}"
How is that organizing correctly if the correct positions would be 0,1,3,5,8

Comment: @johan855 To organize `col1` result you don't need to have actual position, only ascending order of them. It is similiar to "squasing islands" (search for *gap-and-islands-problem*)

Comment: I see, but I cannot then have an array which shows the actual position of each of the actions? so one that shows me:
First time action a happened, it happened at 0
First time b happpened, it happened at 1 and so on

Comment: Yes, that is why I asked question how to calculate second resultset. This answer in current form solves your first question.

Comment: Is it not possible to have an output together with the ordered moments when the actions happened then?

Comment: I didn't say it is not possible. It is not clear for me what you want to achieve with second resultset. That is why I do not answer second part.

Comment: Hey, I removed temporarily the answer to this question since I just stumbled upon a case which does not work, try for instance the following array: array['a','b','a','a','c','a']
Result is: "{a,b,a,a,c}" whereas it should be "{a,b,a,c,a}"

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't have spotted it before.